# Can't access property from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, jsonparser

I need to access properties from this object, but I am getting undefined.

I tried use JSON stringify and parse but without success.

```
console.log('ress', response.data);
console.log('ress data', response.data.url);
console.log('ress key', response.data.key);
```

output:

```
ress {"url":"my url","key":"my key"}
ress data undefined
ress key undefined
```

Comment: Is response modified asynchronously? logging an object will update the values when the object is updated, but logging a string won't.

Comment: Where is the code that populates response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your *response.data* object is a string, in this case you have to parse it into a JSON object to be enable to access the properties.

```
object = JSON.parse(response.data);
console.log('data url', object.url);
```